# Unity can not start a terminal

Tags: command-line, unity

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 client which is member of an active directory domain. Login works, starting applications like firefox or thunderbird works, everything is fine. Except the terminal: I cannot start a terminal window from the unity desktop. Neither gnome-terminal, nor xfce4-terminal nor xterm work. Neither clicking on the dash, nor starting via shortcut work. I do not get any error message.

Remote login into the computer (via ssh), setting the DISPLAY and starting the terminal application works without any problem.

How can I dig deeper into this fancy problem?

Comment: Can you start a tty session with Ctrl + Alt + Fx?

Comment: I can switch to another console via Ctrl+Alt+Fx - which immediatly kills my current session.

Comment: You should be able to switch back with Ctrl + Alt + F2 (I believe). Can you start up a terminal program from there, and see what errors you get?

Comment: @valpo the session is not killed it's kind of like an alt-tab but with an entire screen. you can switch right back to the open desktop environement at any time with Ctrl+Alt+F2 (or F7 depending on the system) you can even, by starting another desktop environement instance on another tty session, have several desktops running at once, although this eats up cpu and ram

Comment: @tatsu believe me: the session was gone. All open applications had been killed. I have checked it via a ssh session: after switching back to the gui session (with the login greeter) no application of the current user was running anymore.

Comment: ah. well then. that's not supposed to happen. it seems your system is unstable. you might have to completely reinstall it. do you have any particual affinity to Unity/18.04?